# What is the meaning of the values in the Android log "thermal_repeater [recvMdThermalInfo]"?

Tags: android, logging, temperature

I am investigating a custom made Android application issue which could be linked to a temperature problem.
I see the following log

**I/thermal_repeater(  448): [recvMdThermalInfo] ret=32, strLen=127,  3, 31, -4, 25236, 32767, -28556**

But I am unable to work out the meaning of the values.
Can anyone help to share some clarity on what this log means?
Thanks in advance

I put my Android device running my application in different hot/cold/normal situations, I see the values changing but I dont know what they represent so I dont know how to interpret the changes.
What I have seen so far is that the value after "ret" seems to range from twenty something to thirty something.
The value after "strLeng" seems to always be 127.
The value after "127" seems to range from 0 to 3.
The last 4 values have a wider integer range.